PyCharm cython hinting won't work with libcpp
I can't get PyCharm to hint methods for libcpp library for example for vector container.
This is my code:
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

cdef vector[int] v

v.push_back(1)


PyCharm can't see methods of v, like size() or push_back(), so it won't hint them. How do I make it work? Cython is installed.
I tried setting up a new project in PyCharm. Tried reinstalling Cython. Tried different kind of imports, different kind of declarations like v: vector[int]

I don't know exactly what PyCharm provides, but I'd be surprised if you can get this to work. I suspect it's mostly just able to tell you about Python objects.

@DavidW Pycharm professional does have cython support and some hinting does work. For example this one works:
from libc cimport math
math.e <- pycharm hints erf() exp() and so on

This is to be expected: those bindings require that the IDE has "understanding" of C/C++ code, which isn't the case for pycharm by default as far as I know
I believe the cyright LSP server is able to check / provide hints for cimport, so you may be able to make it work in pycharm using the LSP plugin.
In particular, this is how this VSCode plugin achieves the expected result.
